# Adding a subject line to PHP form

Tags: php, forms, contacts

So I've put a contact form into my site but I can't seem to add a subject line. (I'm SUPER new to PHP so I'm only about 40% sure of what I'm doing. The rest of the time I'm just learning through trial and error).

Here's what I have for the form:

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/fgcontactform.php");

$formproc = new FGContactForm();

$formproc->AddRecipient('email address');
$formproc->AddSubject('Website Communication:');

$formproc->SetFormRandomKey('boQQEtSLenwppBa');


if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {
        $formproc->RedirectToURL("thank-you.php");
   }
}

?>

<!-- Form Code Start -->
<form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<legend>Contact us</legend>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputName(); ?>' value='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputValue(); ?>'/>
<input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />

<div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>

<div><span class='error'><?php echo $formproc->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <label for='message' >Message:</label><br/>
    <span id='contactus_message_errorloc' class='error'></span>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message'><?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('message') ?></textarea>
</div>


<div class='container'>
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

I added the `$formproc->AddSubject('Website Communication:');` segment but it doesn't seem to be working and I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing?

Comment: the framework/tool you're using to send emails is not the standard PHP way. Whoever made "fgcontactform" should have documentation that will tell you how to do this. do you have a link to their website?

Answer (score 2):

What you're really asking is how to use a specific library class that you've downloaded from the Internet! If you look into the code of the class you're including at the top (which I assume is the same as [this](http://web.mit.edu/bhangra/web_scripts/include/fgcontactform.php)?) then you'll see it's automatically generating a subject line here:

```
$this->mailer->Subject = "Contact form submission from $this->name";
```

The reason your `AddSubject` function doesn't work is because that behaviour doesn't exist within the class.

If you want to change this behaviour, you'll have to change the class. You'll want to change the above line to something like

```
$this->mailer->Subject = $this->getSubject();
```

and implement a `getSubject()` method, similar to the `GetFromAddress()` one.

**Better yet, create your own mailer class! Look into the [PHP mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to get started!**

Comment: Yeah, I pulled the contact form from a site in order to learn how to make it all work. I didn't realize it was creating one on its own already. Thank you so much for your explanation (as well as that link). I really appreciate the patience and encouragement! :)

Comment: The last part of your answer doesn't make any sense... Why should he create his own wrapper/ibrary when there are libraries out there which can manage cc/bcc/atachments/smtp connections/etc.. for you?

Comment: As a learning exercise. Also, when you're addressing a person whose gender you don't know, it's polite to use non-gender-specific pronouns. :)